# Magento1.9 : Translate validation messages for different stores

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, validation

In my having two stores France and German.I want to validation error messages with their particular languages.How can I do it with my Js script?

My code

```
       <label for="sample" class="required"><?php echo $this->__('Sample');?><em>*</em></label>
       <input type="text" name="sample" id="sample" class="input-text required-entry" >
       <label for="test" class="required"><?php echo $this->__('test');?><em>*</em></label>
       <input type="text" name="test" id="test" class="input-text required-entry validate-digits"  maxlength="4" >
```

Js Code

```
     //<![CDATA[
   var brochureform = new VarienForm('form');
    //]]>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is within a custom module you are developing add it to the translation files of that module and register them in `config.xml`. Inchoo [explains](https://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-add-your-own-translations-to-custom-modules/) how to do that.

If this is within a custom theme of yours then you could add this to your `translate.csv` files of that theme. Templatemonster has a [help article](https://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-manage-csv-files-translations.html) about that.

From what I see of your posted code your JS code has no influence on the translations as they come from PHP.